# I need to open my database in an java class which is not linked to any activity

Tags: android

this class is going to select the best thing for the user by comparing values in database to the user entered values.

```
public class Comparator {




    public void findBestCrop() {
       SQLiteOpenHelper AgroDatabase = new AgroDatabase(this);
       SQLiteDatabase db = AgroDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = db.query("userinfo",
               new String[]{"User_Name", "Location", "CurrentNoFields"},
               "_id=?",
               new String[]{Integer.toString(1)}, null, null, null
       );


   }



}
```

But i get error(AgroDatabase cannot be applied) while i provide the paramater (this) in this line SQLiteOpenHelper AgroDatabase = new AgroDatabase(this);

```
Comparator al1= new Comparator();
```

i have created a object of the class in my other java class which is linked to a  activity.
I dont understand why am I not being able to use my database in this case.
DO i need to exetend my class ? I have no idea what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing context from the activity where you were creating a new object as :

```
Comparator al1= new Comparator(YourActivity.this);
```

And in the default constructor pass this constructor to the Class:

```
public class Comparator {

Context mContext;
public void Comparator(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context
}

public void findBestCrop() {
   SQLiteOpenHelper AgroDatabase = new AgroDatabase(mContext );
   SQLiteDatabase db = AgroDatabase.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.query("userinfo",
           new String[]{"User_Name", "Location", "CurrentNoFields"},
           "_id=?",
           new String[]{Integer.toString(1)}, null, null, null
   );
   }
}
```